# Problema con graficas HTML, SQL y JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, sql, json

Que tal compañeros tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy haciendo graficas con la libreria Plotly de JavaScript
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahi todo bien, pero al momento de querer agarrar otra columna de la misma tabla me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla la cual **reembolsos2** y **ganancias** al momento de agregarlas o sustituir por una de las otras me da el **error**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo **Nota: si tengo conexion** el error lo marca en el **while**

```html
require_once("conexion.php");
    $conexion=conexion();
    $sql="SELECT mes, neto, ingresos, orbe, reembolsos FROM reporte";
  //$sql="SELECT mes, neto, ingresos, orbe, reembolsos2 FROM reporte";
  //$sql="SELECT mes, neto, ingresos, orbe, ganancias FROM reporte";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $valoresX=array();//fecha
    $valoresY=array();//montos
    $valoresW=array();
    $valoresZ=array();
    $valoresV=array();
    while ($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $valoresX[]=$ver[0];
        $valoresY[]=$ver[1];
        $valoresW[]=$ver[2];
        $valoresZ[]=$ver[3];
        $valoresV[]=$ver[4];
    }
    $datosX=json_encode($valoresX);
    $datosY=json_encode($valoresY);
    $datosZ=json_encode($valoresZ);
    $datosW=json_encode($valoresW);
    $datosV=json_encode($valoresV);
```

Comment: Hacé un `var_dump($conexion)`, `var_dump($result)` o `echo mysqli_error($conexion)`. Algo tenés mal, porque evidentemente `$result` es `false`.

Comment: Pero si cambio de columna si me lo muestra bien, me trae los campos de la base de datos sin problema incluso si cambio datos de las columnas mes, neto, ingresos, orbe, reembolsos me funciona sin problema

Comment: Te entiendo, pero si se está generando un error hay que ver cual es. Hacé el echo de `mysqli_error()`.